# Do secure elements with microSD interface exist?

Tags: key-management

I would like to add a secure element to an embedded system so that I can safely store keys. The system has an unused microSD slot.

I know that in the past it was possible to use SD cards with SDIO to add wifi to systems that did not support wifi.

Do secure elements based on SDIO or similar technology exist with microSD factor form? I am not interested in NFC or wireless technology

Comment: In general, yes. This might be what you're searching for: https://www.smartcard-hsm.com/features.html#microsd .